# How can i take a video without render

Tags: rendering, animation, blender-internal-render-engine, video, timeline

I want to make animation on blender but first i need to see how speed my models in animation. Render is taking very long time and i can't use timeline because fps is very low. this mean i can't understand my models fast moving or slow moving. I want to take o video without render. How can do this?

Comment: You can do OpenGL preview render of the viewport: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/opengl.html. But such workflow is not feasible. You need to see the results in real-time to be productive. You have to simplify the scene and use simple proxy objects in viewport that represent the highpoly ones and enable the highpoly only for render.

Comment: Or you can try rendering with Low samples at a low resolution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do a preview render using the OpenGL renderer. This will pretty much be as quick as in the viewport.

More info in the Blender documentation:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/opengl.html